# Trying to retrieve data from wp DB

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to retrieve data from wp database here with my plugin code below. I have manually added records in the db but my plugin doesn't want to retrieve my data. I don't know where am I going wrong here.

```
<?php
    /**
     * Plugin Name: Member Details         
     */

    function custom_view() {
     global $wpdb;          

     echo '<table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Bank</th>
        <th>Account Number</th>
        <th>Deposited Amount</th>
        <th>Deposit Date</th>
        <th>Period [Days]</th>            
      </tr>';
     $results = $wpdb->get_results("select * from users"); 

     foreach( $results as $user_data) {                  
      // $roi = $user_data->amount * $user_data->period;  
      // $amount_growth = $roi - $user_data->amount;

       echo "<tr>
        <td>$user_data->user_nicename</td>
        <td>$user_data->user_email</td>
        <td>$user_data->bank</td>
        <td>$user_data->account_num</td>
        <td>$user_data->amount</td>
        <td>$user_data->deposit_date</td>
        <td>$user_data->period</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>";
     }
     echo '</table>';         
    }
    add_shortcode('views', 'custom_view');
    ?>
```

Can somebody help me here? Thanks

Comment: Improved formatting, deleted some unnecessary comments & lines.

Answer (score 0):

Two important things:

**1°** your data was not returning because you did not pass the table prefix, ie the table name was wrong.
Example "users" is correct "wp_users" or the prefix you used when creating in the database.
You can use the **$wpdb->users** variable which will automatically return it with the prefix you registered in wp

**2°** shortcodes must always end in a **return** and not in **echo**.
I left an example for you to call with php manually if you want to use it. but you can use it directly in the editor just by calling shortcode normally :)

If my answer helps you. Vote and put as right answer to close this question please :)

```
<?php 

    /**
 * Plugin Name:       Member Details
 * Plugin URI:        https://mysite.co.za
 * Description:       All Member Details List 
 * Version:           1.0
 * Author:            Empire Investment
 * Author URI:        https://mysite.co.za
 */

function custom_view() {
 global $wpdb;


 $output .= '<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Bank</th>
    <th>Account Number</th>
    <th>Deposited Amount</th>
    <th>Deposit Date</th>
    <th>Period [Days]</th>

  </tr>';
 $results = $wpdb->get_results("select * from $wpdb->users"); 

 foreach( $results as $user_data) {


// $roi = $user_data->amount * $user_data->period;  
// $amount_growth = $roi - $user_data->amount;


 $output .= "<tr>
    <td>$user_data->user_nicename</td>
    <td>$user_data->user_email</td>
    <td>$user_data->bank</td>
    <td>$user_data->account_num</td>
    <td>$user_data->amount</td>
    <td>$user_data->deposit_date</td>
    <td>$user_data->period</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>";
 }
 $output .= '</table>';

 return $output;
}
add_shortcode('views', 'custom_view');

//example usae with php
echo do_shortcode( $content, '[custom_view]' );
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct to close the question. Thanks for voting and I'm glad I could help you. :D